# When performing the API Load testing getting the error related to database

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i have API builds with .NET Core 7 and doing the load testing with 100 users at that time i getting this type of errors randomly "**An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.**" can any one having a solution about this error.

i used the PostgreSQL 14.8 version with 4GB ram.

solution or any suggestions for above error.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71238301/an-exception-has-been-raised-that-is-likely-due-to-a-transient-failure-connect)  .

Comment: @QingGuo this will not work. we have not running in the same port.

Comment: @QingGuo i already added EnableRetryOnFailure in startup file. but still getting this error so its a code side or server side error.

Comment: How about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840282/error-when-connect-database-continuously) ?

Comment: @QingGuo can we use the transaction commit and roll back  to resolve this errors .